# In Unity, how can I make smooth movement in a slow framerate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame, frame-rate

When the target frame rate is greater than 30, its okay. Movements are good and the game is playable. But when the things going like 10-20 target frame rate, it's not getting what I want. The result is laggy and unplayable. So basicly my question is this.

Unity's self Lerp function isn't working right now.
Well, its working but the result is not what I want. Still the things are laggy.

Im assigning "TargetFrameRate" value to "Application.targetFrameRate" in my code somewhere
[From Inspector Show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EPwO.png)

I tried to use Kalman Filter for this. The result a little bit better but no so quite closer to what I expect.
Filtered Values:

```
      float filteredX = kalmanFilterFloat.Update(p.value.x);
      float filteredY = kalmanFilterFloat.Update(p.value.y);
      float filteredZ = kalmanFilterFloat.Update(p.value.z);
```

Here im simulating filtired lerp:

```
  private void SimulateFilteredLerp(InterpolatedProperty<Vector3> p, Vector3 filteredVec) 
  {
    p.prevValue = p.value = Vector3.Lerp(p.value + new Vector3(filteredVec.x,
    filteredVec.y, filteredVec.z) * masterClock.delta, p.target, masterClock.delta * settings.interpolationSnapping);
  }
```

Applying filtered vector:

```
      Vector3 filteredVec = new Vector3((float)filteredX, (float)filteredY, (float)filteredZ);
```

Calling function in Update

```
      SimulateFilteredLerp(p, filteredVec);
```

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: Why are you lowering the target frame rate in the first place? 10-20 FPS is laggy, so I'm not really sure what you are expecting

Comment: Game should work with other platforms, so as you expect some of the other devices, game's fps could be lower than the other ones. Thus, the reason behind this: Even the frame rate goes down, game objects must move smoother. @UnholySheep

Comment: I added now the code to the my question @Iggy